# Create an independent process in C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

How can I create an independent process (by independent I mean that if I stop the programm which called it, the process won't stop) from a C++ executable in Windows?

This process is to run a Windows cmd command from it.

Comment: In Windows, all processes are independent of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [CreateProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to do that.